# I'm trying to run a code in the powershell of my laptop and getting this error. "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not pr

Tags: powershell

I am running this code in the powershell of my windows 11 laptop and getting an error

The code:
`[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; iex "& { $((iwr -useb 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amd64fox/SpotX/main/Install.ps1').Content) } -new_theme"`

This is the error I'm getting.
"Invoke-WebRequest: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

Comment: The error means the website doesn't answer, and Powershell gives up after waiting for a while. Try to access it with a browser and see if the resource is accessible.

Comment: try both TLS 1.2 and 1,3  [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 -or [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls13

Comment: Thanks for the replies, it worked when I ran the code using a VPN. I think it was a problem with the Auto-DNS of my broadband network.